# Relative error reduction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please forgive me a really simple question: Am I calculating the relative error reduction correctly?

Example: Model 1 gets 80/100 examples wrong, model 2 gets only 20/100 examples wrong, so the 80 errors are reduced by 60, which is an error reduction of 75%.

So the relative error reduction formula seems to be

```
(m1_error - m2_error) / m1_error * 100.0
```

What if it's vice versa? Model 1 gets 20/100 wrong, but model 2 gets 80/100 wrong. By what amount does model 2 "reduce" the error? The formula gives -300%, so it increases the  error by 300%.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does make sense.  Reducing the error by -300% is increasing it by 300%.  And increasing 20 by 300% gives 80.